# Filter dictionary list by text in string

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries and need to filter them by a list of strings.

Right now I have this:

```
projects = [{u'CustomerName': u'abc', u'Projectname': u'Contract A full'},
{u'CustomerName': u'bcd', u'Projectname': u'Contract A medium'},
{u'CustomerName': u'cde', u'Projectname': u'Contract B full'},
{u'CustomerName': u'def', u'Projectname': u'Contract B medium'}]

filter = ['B', 'full']

return [p for p in projects if p['ProjectName'] in filter]
```

The result I need is:

```
[{u'CustomerName': u'abc', u'Projectname': u'Contract A full'},
{u'CustomerName': u'cde', u'Projectname': u'Contract B medium'},
{u'CustomerName': u'cde', u'Projectname': u'Contract B full'}]
```

However it returns nothing. Only if I specify the entire string:

```
filter = ['Contract A full', 'Contract B full']
```

Thank's for the help.

Comment: You will need to split the each value of the `Projectname` key and then check the second and third element to see if the are in `filter`.

Comment: Also, don't use `filter` as a variable name in python. It is a reserved keyword and could cause confusion or unexpected outcomes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one way, assuming you are looking for ProjectNames containing 'full':

```
[p for p in projects if 'full' in p['ProjectName']]
```

Or if you need containing 'B' or 'full':

```
[p for p in projects if any(i in p['ProjectName'] for i in ('B', 'full'))]
```

Comment: This worked, more specifically [p for p in projects if any(i in p['ProjectName'] for i in filter)]. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

The marked answer is a very elegant way out, especially for the "any" part.

Here is another way using regular expression:

```
import re
[p for p in projects if re.match(".*(B|full).*",p["Projectname"])]
```

".*" basically means anything any occurrence, this regex implies you're looking for the occurrence of "B" or "full" with anything in front and behind it.

Though you might encounter some cases where it would match unexpected things such as "Contract fuller-house medium" or some other things, regex does work on simple cases like the one you presented without too much trouble.